# Getting Leaked window and End of character 3 of Errors

Tags: android

If have two errors:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 3 of & FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
```

And:

```
Activity rng.events.LoginActivity has leaked window at rng.events.LoginActivity$LogInUser.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:84)
```

The issue is, after registration it logs you in automatically, once you log out and force close the application, and try loggin in again I get these errors.

The code for LoginActivity is below.

```
    package rng.events;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import JSONnDB.DatabaseHandler;
    import JSONnDB.UserFunctions;

    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        Button btnLogin;
        Button btnLinkToRegister;
        EditText inputEmail;
        EditText inputPassword;
        TextView loginErrorMsg;

        // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
        private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
        private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
        private static String KEY_F_NAME = "f_name";
        private static String KEY_L_NAME = "l_name";
        private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
            loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

            // Login button Click Event
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new LogInUser().execute();
                }
            });

            // Link to Register Screen
            btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Create new product
         * */
        class LogInUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..Please Wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        int res = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(res == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_F_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_L_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                     

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            //loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                            Log.i("Log in: ", "Error occured while loggin in");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }   
    }
```

Logcat output

```
06-11 13:57:08.139: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 4% free 6528K/6787K, paused 28ms
06-11 13:57:08.149: I/dalvikvm-heap(794): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.861MB for 448916-byte allocation
06-11 13:57:08.199: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 4% free 6963K/7239K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-11 13:57:08.269: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 444K, 10% free 6747K/7495K, paused 19ms
06-11 13:57:08.279: I/dalvikvm-heap(794): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.647MB for 1048592-byte allocation
06-11 13:57:08.319: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 7771K/8583K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-11 13:57:08.339: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 7771K/8583K, paused 15ms
06-11 13:57:08.339: I/dalvikvm-heap(794): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.090MB for 465140-byte allocation
06-11 13:57:08.359: D/dalvikvm(794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 8225K/9095K, paused 14ms
06-11 13:57:08.429: D/libEGL(794): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-11 13:57:08.439: D/libEGL(794): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-11 13:57:08.449: D/libEGL(794): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-11 13:57:08.449: D/libEGL(794): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-11 13:57:08.469: D/OpenGLRenderer(794): Enabling debug mode 0
06-11 13:57:17.339: D/Button(794): Login
06-11 13:57:17.659: E/JSON(794):        
06-11 13:57:17.659: E/JSON Parser(794): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 3 of       
06-11 13:57:17.669: W/dalvikvm(794): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409d91f8)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at rng.events.LoginActivity$LogInUser.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:95)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at rng.events.LoginActivity$LogInUser.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-11 13:57:17.669: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  ... 5 more
06-11 13:57:17.939: D/OpenGLRenderer(794): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-11 13:57:17.959: D/OpenGLRenderer(794): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-11 13:57:18.259: D/OpenGLRenderer(794): Flushing caches (mode 1)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794): Activity rng.events.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4106d338 that was originally added here
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity rng.events.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4106d338 that was originally added here
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at rng.events.LoginActivity$LogInUser.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:82)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at rng.events.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:58)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-11 13:57:18.269: E/WindowManager(794):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the logcat and the JSON string that causes the error.

Comment: I think the second exception is thrown, because of the error in `doInBackground()`. This prevents the dismissal of the progressDialog. So if you fix the first problem, you fix the second one as well. But for that, we really need the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

The LeakedWindow exception is most probably related to the progress dialog that you used in the asynctask. It's because you called finish() before onPostExecute() can run to dismiss the dialog.

Add this to your activity:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    if ( pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing() ){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it didnt work, still get the same error.